# Don't know why the plot() function is not working in this code

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=10
sy=2
x=10




while x<=100:
    draw_line(x,0,x,y)
    y=sy*y
    x=x+10

    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

Basically I used scatter function to get through the exam but plot is not working at all.
when ran it was a blank screen.
I tried to find solutions online and checked the syntax but there doesn't seem to be any problem
I checked my matplotlib installation as well and ran it online as well
same problem

Comment: please provide the code for `draw_line`

Answer (score 0):

To draw a curve, you need to collect all the x and all the y value into a list (or a numpy array) and then call plot once.  `plot` by default, tries to draw a line. If you just call `plt.plot(x,y)` where `x` and `y` are single values, no line can be drawn.

Also, `plt.show()` should only be called once, at the end of the code, outside the `for` loop.

To draw vertical lines between `0` and the `ys`, you could try `plt.stem(xs, ys)`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = 10
sy = 2
x = 10

xs = []
ys = []

while x <= 100:
     xs.append(x)
     ys.append(y)
     y = sy * y
     x = x + 10

plt.plot(xs, ys)
# plt.stem(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

[image: line plot from points]